# Want to run an Object Array into a Generic Constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor

```
class CircularArrayDeque<E> implements Deque {
  private E[] items;
  private int currentSize, capacity, front, back;
  private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

  public CircularArrayDeque(Collection<? extends E> other) {     
    items = (E[]) other.toArray();
    currentSize = other.size();
    front = 0;
    back = currentSize - 1;
  }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = {8, 7, 5, 3, 6, 7, 12, 4};
}
```

I want to be able to run arr into the constructor CircularArrayDeque(arr). Deque is just an interface I wrote up, it's not the one of java's class. I'm not sure exactly how I can do that if that is even possible. Or could I change my arr to an Object Integer like.....

```
Integer[] arr = {8, 7, 5, 3, 6, 7, 12, 4};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
final Collection<Integer> coll = Arrays.asList(8, 7, 5, 3, 6, 7, 12, 4);
```